# Accessing Attributes of SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xpath, simplexml

I have the following code :

```
     $doc=new DOMDocument(); 
     $doc->loadHTML($content); 
     $xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple 
     //$images=$xml->xpath('(//img[@class = "thumbimage"])[1]');

     for($x=1;$x<=5;$x++)
     {
                      $images[] = $xml->xpath('(//img[@class = "thumbimage"])['.$x.']'); 

     }
```

I i dump $images I get this type of array see screen shot at the bottom

```
  [array](unknown name)
   - [array]0
     -[SimpleXMLElement Object] 0
      -Properties
        -[array]@attributes
              [string]src = "thestring"
      -Methods
        __construct
        __addAttribute etc
```

I want to get "thestring" from each of the $images[] Array

Please see attached image:

[image]

Comment: I added the PHP (because your code is PHP although your question isn't PHP specific so maybe I shouldn't have) and XML tags.

Comment: I added more of the code so you can render the xml via the api call

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need the correct XPath and that'll be tons easier to give if you posted the XML you're dealing with (I can only infer some stuff from the image you provided). Anyways you're using img[@class = '...'] so I'll assume the that element name we're dealing with is called `img`

In which case the xpath that you need is

```
"//img@src"
```

Use @ to select an attributes of all img elements. http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: //img@src doesnt bring back results this does bring back the 1st image : $images=$xml->xpath('(//img[@class = "thumbimage"])[1]'); i need the first five images. I am not family with the syntax to get these attributes directly...

Comment: The XPath "//img@src" should return the src attributes of all the img elements. Maybe you should post your XML (not all of it, just enough of us to know exactly what you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can access attributes as elements of array:

```
$images[$i]['src']
```

Comment: I tried this but it only brings back the SimpleXMLObject with Unknown Name and its methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for($x=0;$x<=5;$x++)
               {
                $k = $x + 1;
                $images[] = $xml->xpath('(//img[@class = "thumbimage"])['.$k.']'); 
                $url[] = (string)$images[$x][0]['src'];
               }
```

This is what gave me the results i wanted.